# Turning list of lists into objects

Tags: python, list, class

I currently have a list of lists where every list consists of the same kind of information, say:

```
[['Planet Name', 16, 19, 27, 11], ['Planet Name 2', 12, 22, 11, 42], ....]
```

and I would like to use a class to make this into a list of objects with the same information, where index 0 is self.name, index 1 is self.distance and so on for every seperate list.

I know that I need to use some kind of a for loop, but have no idea how to go about and do this.

I would really appreciate some help, trying to learn Python and currently classes!

Comment: Please elaborate on: "where index 0 is self.name, index 1 is self.distance and so on" What are the names of the fields you want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well... To make a class like you want you can do something like this:

```
class Planet(object):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.name = args[0]
        self.distance = args[1]
        # ... etc ...
```

Or something like this:

```
class Planet(object):
    def __init__(self, name, distance, ...):
        self.name = name
        self.distance = distance
        # ... etc ...
```

And then you call it like this:

```
p = Planet(*['Planet Name', 16, 19, 27, 11])
```

In a loop that would be:

```
l = [['Planet Name', 16, 19, 27, 11], ['Planet Name 2', 12, 22, 11, 42], ....]
planets = [Planet(*data) for data in l]
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use [namedtuple](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) like this, to create an object dynamically, with the list of field names. `*item` in this code is called, [unpacking of arguments list](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists)

```
from collections import namedtuple
Planet = namedtuple("Planet", ["name", "distance", "a", "b", "c"])

data = [['Planet Name', 16, 19, 27, 11],['Planet Name 2', 12, 22, 11, 42]] 
for item in data:
    planet = Planet(*item)
    print planet.name, planet.distance, planet
```

**Output**

```
Planet Name 16 Planet(name='Planet Name', distance=16, a=19, b=27, c=11)
Planet Name 2 12 Planet(name='Planet Name 2', distance=12, a=22, b=11, c=42)
```

**Note:** `namedtuple` is a subclass of `tuple`. So, all the objects created with `namedtuple` are immutable. It means that, once the object is created, data in the member variables cannot be changed.

Comment: I like this answer, but it should come with the disclaimer that namedtuples are immutable

Answer (score 1):

I'm confused. Have you created the Planet constructor yet? 
The code would be something like:

```
class Planet(object):
    def __init__(self, ....):

....

planets = [['Planet Name', 16, 19, 27, 11]['Planet Name 2', 12, 22, 11, 42]....] 
planet_list = [Planet(*p) for p in planets]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to have a constructor (`__init__`) which knows about the specifics of your lists, you could do it like this

```
lists = [['Planet Name', 16, 19, 27, 11], ['Planet Name 2', 12, 22, 11, 42]]

class Planet(object):
    pass

for l in lists:
    planet = Planet()
    setattr(planet, 'name', l[0])
    setattr(planet, 'distance', l[1])
    setattr(planet, 'size', l[2])
    print planet.name, planet.distance, planet.size
```